# Texturing problem distorted and messed up

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm having a little trouble with texturing this blasted coffee cup- When I place the texture onto it it comes out warbled and distorted.

[image]

Comment: Does it also look like that in rendered view?

Comment: it looks like you have a lot of vertices along your vertical edges, you should try to delete them with a X > Dissolve vertices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a lot of vertices along your vertical edges, you should try to delete them with a <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve vertices* and see what happens.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I deleted those extra vertices and it totally did the trick!